# A negation of a statement sounds wrong?

Tags: logic

I have the statement "Any non-negative number that is smaller than any positive number is zero", which I quantified as (assuming $U=\mathbb{R}$)
$$(\forall \: x \ge 0)[(x < \varepsilon)(\forall \: \varepsilon > 0) \implies (x = 0)]$$
Negating:
$$(\exists \: x \ge 0)[(x < \varepsilon)(\forall \: \varepsilon > 0) \land (x \neq  0)]$$
Which I interpret as "There exists a non-negative, non-zero number that is smaller than any positive number". Is this the proper negation? Can a quantifier+predicate statement and its negation have the same or opposite truth value?

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised that the negation of a true sentence is false! If you mean to construct the same statement using an existential quantifier, then you're missing a negation; you want to map $\forall x f(x)$ to $\neg(\exists x \neg f(x))$.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes, this is a proper negation. But what is this about "same or opposite truth value"?

Comment: @DavidK It's a bit far from the original question (which is just about if I properly negated a (true) sentence). What I asked is if I negated a true sentence (of quantifier+predicate form), does that mean that the negated sentence is also true (same truth value) or false (opposite). The former is absurd so it must be the latter

Comment: That's right, if a sentence has a truth value then its negation has the opposite truth value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the statement "Any non-negative number that is smaller than any positive number is zero", which I quantified as (assuming $U=\mathbb{R}$)
> $$(\forall \: x \ge 0)[(x < \varepsilon)(\forall \: \varepsilon > 0) \implies (x = 0)]$$

When formalising a statement, the convention is that each predicate's quantifiers precede the predicate, and the quantifiers then read from left to right (changing their order generally alters the statement's meaning).

So, correction: $$\forall x{\ge}0\;\Big(\forall \varepsilon{>}0\; x < \varepsilon \implies x = 0\Big).$$

> Negating:
> $$(\exists \: x \ge 0)[(x < \varepsilon)(\forall \: \varepsilon > 0) \land (x \neq  0)]$$

Similar correction: $$\exists x{\ge}0\;\Big(\forall \varepsilon{>}0\; x < \varepsilon \;\land\; x \ne 0\Big).$$

This means that there exists some positive number such that it is smaller than every positive number.

> Can a quantifier+predicate statement and its negation have the same or opposite truth value?

Negating a statement flips its truth value. In the above example, negating a true statement creates a false statement.